# notepad++ remove line with blank space

Tags: full-text-search, notepad++

i have multiple document which has lines which starts with blank space. those lines should be removed.
how can one remove a line which contains a blank space in the beginning and no other chars?

Comment: i suggest that you accept an answer that most fit what you needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find and Replace (Ctrl + h) than on Search Mode settings check Regular expression. After you sett the box to search with regex patterns enter this into the Find what field: ^([ ]+)$ and leave the replace field empty. Than click Replace All. That's it.

This will find all lines starting with a space character (may contain more that one space) but that have NO other character after the space/s.

Comment: This won't work, this will only replace lines that contain only spaces. You are missing a `.*` after the `[ ]+`.

Comment: If you add .* it will replace all lines that begin with a space even if they have other characters after the spaces witch could lead to undesirable replacements.

Comment: I misread the question, I was under the impression that is what he wanted. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

With Notepad++, you can use regular expression search and replace.

Go to Replace, select "Regular Expression" in the Search Mode box, and enter the following search expression:

```
\r\n \r\n
```

This means: newline, space, newline.

Replace by nothing. That should do the trick!

Comment: thanks i will try right away edit:it works! but as extended! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is in Notepad++

Search

Replace

Find what: `^ +$`

Replace with: (blank)

Search Mode: Regular expression

Answer (score 2):

I my case regEx not solve the problem, I use plugin TextFX and I solve like this:
delete all spaces: 
[image]

delete lines:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit-> Line Operations->Remove Empty Lines(Containing Blank Characters)